# how to remove half of the dictionary items based on value (DateTime) with LINQ in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a dictionary:

```
private Dictionary<long, TimeStampedFetchedPlans> remainingPlansById = null;
```

where

```
public class TimeStampedFetchedPlans
{
    public DateTime TimeStamp { get; set; }
    public List<TFetchedPlanReturn> RemainingPlans { get; set; }

    public TimeStampedFetchedPlans(DateTime timeStamp, List<TFetchedPlanReturn> remainingPlans)
    {
        TimeStamp = timeStamp;
        RemainingPlans = remainingPlans;
    }
}
```

Now I would like to remove oldest half of the values in Dictionary using LINQ. Can this be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it purely with LINQ by creating a new instance:

```
remainingPlansById = remainingPlansById.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value.TimeStamp)
                                       .Take(remainingPlansById.Count / 2)
                                       .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

However, using a loop wouldn't require the creation of a new dictionary:

```
var itemsToRemove = remainingPlansById.OrderBy(x => x.Value.TimeStamp)
                                      .Take(remainingPlansById.Count / 2)
                                      .ToList();

foreach(var itemToRemove in itemsToRemove)
    remainingPlansById.Remove(itemToRemove.Key);
```

Please note that the two versions are behaving differently for an uneven number of items. For 41 items in the dictionary, the first version will *keep* 20 and remove *21* while the second version will *remove* 20 and *keep* 21. Each version can be easily changed to the other, you just need to decide what behaviour you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the Linq method "OrderBy" on the dictionary and then use the Linq method "take" methode in combination with the count method to only read the half of the dictionary?